# Rails couldn't find user without id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Okay so some one please explain to me why is this error showing up

profile.html

```
<%= @user.username %>
```

profile.controller

```
class InterfaceController < ApplicationController
    #before_action :authenticate_user!

    def profile
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
end
```

i have read probably every post on stack overflow with the same error but non of them helped me. I would really appreciate the help and a explanation.

Routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           posts#index
                 profile GET    /profile(.:format)                          interface#profile
           post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
```

Comment: `params[:user_id]` is probably `nil`. What does your route look like? Show me `bin/rake routes`

Comment: check the server log, it should tell you which params are submitted

Comment: Please post in your question the value of `params[:user_id]`

Comment: shouldn't it be `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @Abhinay i've updated the post

Comment: @BilalMaqsood i've updated the post

Comment: @prusswan i've updated the post

Comment: @sjagr i've updated the post

Comment: `profile GET    /profile(.:format)  interface#profile` this is for GET not POST right?

Comment: @Abhinay yep it is

Comment: So, you are not trying to `POST` the `:user_id` to this route I hope.

Comment: how does your URL looks like on `profile` page?

Comment: @Abhinay localhost:3000/profile , maybe you will understand better if i will try to tell you what i want, so i want to make it a user profile out of it .. but you probably guessed it already :P

Comment: thats why its complaining about not having `:user_id` because in case of GET, it tries to read the `:id` from URL. which is not present in your case.

Comment: @Abhinay oh thank you i will keep that one in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

```
profile GET    /profile(.:format)                          interface#profile
```

This doesn't match your controller correctly. You should change your `routes.rb` file such that you're passing a `:user_id` into the controller. Your resulting route should look like this:

```
profile GET    /profile/:user_id(.:format)                          interface#profile
```

You can achieve this by using a `resource` or adding the parameter explicitly in the routes file. See [resources routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and [bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters). I'd recommend the former.

If you're trying to make a profile of a user, I'd also suggest keeping it within the same controller and resource route namespace instead of making a new "Interface" controller.

Comment: i didn't quite understand how to chenge it in routes.rb my current route looks like this  get 'profile', to: 'interface#profile', as: 'profile'

Comment: In that case, you can do `get 'profile/:user_id', to: 'interface#profile', as: 'profile'`